# MySQL procedure to check next free value

Tags: mysql, sql

How should i write procedure which will check next free number (which is string) based on input. 
Procedure should have 2 input value, first one is user input (numbers) and second one is maximum amount of characters in string.

This is procedure i tried to write:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getfreenum`(IN num CHAR(20), IN maxval CHAR(20))
begin

set @compare := (num + num *10);

set @maxId := (select sifra from artikli where sifra >=  @compare order by sifra asc limit 1);

while @compare = @maxId do
    set @compare := @compare + 1;
    set @maxId = (select sifra from artikli where sifra >=  @compare order by sifra asc limit 1);
end while;

select @compare;
end
```

This procedure finds me next available value after my input but it does not include my input in that number, meaning if i call procedure `Call getfreenum(1,5)` i get value `779` but i should get next 5 char value which includes input number, which is `1`.

So a `Call getfreenum(1,5)` procedure should return 10043 if everything is taken from 10000 to and including 100042 and `Call getfreenum(11,5)` should check for remaining 3 characters and return let's say 11000. Or 11600 if everything is taken from 11000 to 11599. And it should work like that for every input, even if i enter 4 characters: `Call getfreenum(1234,5)` procedure should check for 12340, 12341, 12342 and if 12349 is free it should return that, but it should not return value which changes input number, meaning, if I call `Call getfreenum(1234,5)` and everything is taken including '123459' then function should return NULL or some fixed value for all errors.

Comment: Does it have to be a `char(20)`? This would be a lot easier and more efficient with `decimal(20,0)`.

Comment: It does not have to be, as long as it returns correct values

Comment: Also, why is it constrained by the maximum number of digits? That seems odd. Shouldn't it be within a range? Like `getfreenum(10000, 11000)` to get the highest number between 10000 and 11000? What is this function being used for?

Comment: Function is used for asigning item numbers to items in a shop. Sometimes for some items maximum number of digits is 3 and sometimes it is 5. Some items have starting numbers: let's say "1254" for cigarettes. and "12" are starting numbers for luxury goods. It is easier for cashier to use this logic when assigning item numbers. it's just more complex for me :) @Schwern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the set of all `sifra` where `sifra + 1` does not exist with `NOT EXISTS` and a correlated subquery.

`num * power(10, maxval - floor(log10(num)) - 1)` gives you the minimum number, e.g. 21000 for 21, 5 and `num * power(10, maxval - floor(log10(num)) - 1) + power(10, maxval - floor(log10(num)) - 1)` gives you one more than the maximum number, e.g. 22000 for 21, 5. Compare `sifra + 1` against it accordingly.

Finally you have to make sure the requested number of digits does not exceed the number of digits for the given prefix. I.e. `floor(log10(num)) < maxval` has to be satisfied.

To make sure at least the predecessor `num * power(10, maxval - floor(log10(num)) - 1) - 1` of the minimum number exists use `UNION ALL` to add it to the base set.

Like that you can calculate the number with just a `SELECT`, without any (possibly relatively slow) loops.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getfreenum
                 (IN num integer,
                  IN maxval integer)
BEGIN
  SELECT CASE
           WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                   FROM artikli t2
                                   WHERE t2.sifra = num * power(10, maxval - floor(log10(num)) - 1)) THEN
             num * power(10, maxval - floor(log10(num)) - 1)
           ELSE
             min(t1.sifra) + 1
         END sifra
         FROM artikli t1
         WHERE floor(log10(num)) < maxval
               AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                                  FROM artikli t2
                                  WHERE sifra = num * power(10, maxval - floor(log10(num)) - 1))
               AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                      FROM artikli t2
                                      WHERE t2.sifra = t1.sifra + 1)
               AND t1.sifra >= num * power(10, maxval - floor(log10(num)) - 1) - 1
               AND t1.sifra < num * power(10, maxval - floor(log10(num)) - 1) + power(10, maxval - floor(log10(num)) - 1) - 1;
END;
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hiJGYtNhJAp72qH9RXVJc7/3)

And if you're dealing with numbers you should use an appropriate type, not `char`.

Comment: This actually does the trick and it is a solution i needed, at least in Fiddle. Running it against my database hangs and does not finish inside 30 seconds because i have 115k+ rows inside. the only thing is there are items with item codes that start with but i can avoid that. @Stickybit

Comment: @stacks: I tweaked the code a little to have constants only one side of operations. Try the edit and make sure you have an index on `artikli (sifra)`.

Comment: I will mark this as a solution because it does the trick. Now i will have to check my table and see why it's so slow. Thank you sir

Comment: One more question, some existing item numbers start with '0' that's why i wanted it to be CHAR. Is this or something similar to this appliable to those kind of fields?

Comment: @stacks: Updated it once again to get rid of the `UNION ALL` which might have prevented the use of the index.

Comment: @stacks: I'm afraid 0s may break it. Maybe you can work around something with `lpad()`.

Comment: I have figured out why this procedure is slow, it is because i'm using VARCHAR to store item numbers and i guess there is no way to implement this procedure (which indeed works and works really well on integers) to my table which stores item numbers as VARCHAR. I guess i will have to do it some other way. I have to store values that way because some item numbers are '00001', '00002', etc...

Answer (score 2):

> *Function is used for asigning item numbers to items in a shop. Sometimes for some items maximum number of digits is 3 and sometimes it is 5. Some items have starting numbers: let's say "1254" for cigarettes. and "12" are starting numbers for luxury goods. It is easier for cashier to use this logic when assigning item numbers. it's just more complex for me :) @Schwern – stacks 3 mins ago*

This is better handled with better schema design.

Recognize that "1254" is really two parts. There's the category ID 12 and the item ID 54. Rather than store "1254" you'd store these two separately.

```
create table item_categories(
    id integer primary key auto_increment,
    shop_id_padding integer not null default 5,
    name text not null
);
create table items (
    id integer primary key auto_increment,
    name text not null,
    category_id integer not null,
    foreign key(category_id) references item_categories(id)
);
```

An explicit `item_categories` table gives us referential integrity, a place to store the category name, as well as how much padding to use.

Now you can let `auto_increment` do its job.

```
insert into item_categories (id, name, shop_id_padding) values (12, "cigarettes", 2);
insert into items (name, category_id) values ("Coffin Nails", 12);
insert into items (name, category_id) values ("Death Sticks", 12);

select * from items;
+----+--------------+-------------+
| id | name         | category_id |
+----+--------------+-------------+
|  1 | Coffin Nails |          12 |
|  2 | Death Sticks |          12 |
+----+--------------+-------------+
```

Construct the shop ID using `concat`. Pad the ID according to the category.

```
select concat(i.category_id, lpad(i.id, cat.shop_id_padding, '0')) as shop_id
from items i
join item_categories cat on i.category_id = cat.id;
+---------+
| shop_id |
+---------+
| 1201    |
| 1202    |
+---------+
```